# How do I get a list of all users who have uploaded a file

Tags: file-upload

My manager is asking me to get a list of all users who have uploaded a file larger than 10 Mb in the past 90 days  to each site we host.  I am new to SP so someone please help.

Comment: More info needed... SharePoint version? SharePoint Online? Selected sites/libraries, all Site Collections and all libraries?

Answer (score 2):

While this may not be 100% complete, it should be close.

1. Go to your Enterprise Search Center (or do a search from a site search box and select "Everything".
2. Search for:

   created>1/1/2018 AND size>10000000 AND IsDocument=true

Note that the "AND" must be in upper case.

You can mouse-over each document to see the user's name in the popup or see the list of user in the Author refiners on the left of the page.

Comment: one last tip I can think of is that search shows results you have permissions to so that may change the outcome. (unless your an admin) ;-)